# How to cycle between instances of the same apps quickly with a lot of apps open or to cycle between apps in the main monitor

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar, task-manager

Is there any way without 3rd party programs to cycle between multiple instances of the same app without the use of 3rd party software in Windows 10?

Or a way to only cycle between apps on the monitor you are working

For example, I have 10 instances of the calculator open, number from 1 to 10, and I want to know if there is any shortcut to cycle between them in an order, so each time I press the shortcut it will switch to the next instance.

I know about <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> shortcut but if I have too much apps it starts to be a chaos.

A 3rd party program that does what I want to is for example "Windows Tabs" but I want to know if there is any way to do it in Windows without 3rd party programs.

I have already tried:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click on the taskbar (since you cannot order instances of the same app on windows taskbar this do not work)
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (position of the app, this do not work for instances of the same app)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

Comment: I [edited the question](https://superuser.com/posts/1749157/revisions) already, but found it very odd to see “3º” when it should have been “3rd.” That º means “degrees” which is not close to “rd.”

Comment: oh, sorry, totally forgot that in english u cannot use "3º" as an abbreviation of third. Thanks for the correction

Comment: `win+n (position of the app, this do not work for instances of the same app)`: what does not work in that case? Does it not switch to other instances when you press it repeatedly?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [pinning apps to the taskbar](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/pin-apps-and-folders-to-the-desktop-or-taskbar-f3c749fb-e298-4cf1-adda-7fd635df6bb0).

Pinned apps are assigned a shortcut automatically depending on their position in the taskbar, e.g.: the app pinned closes to the start button can be opened with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, the second app with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, etc...

To access different windows of a pinned app, you simply have to press the corresponding shortcut repeatedly, e.g.: to access the 4th window of an app pinned right next to the start button you press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> 4 times.

Other related shortcuts are (keeping the first pinned app as an example):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>: Switch to the last window of the pinned app.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>: Cycle through the windows of the pinned app in reverse order.

Comment: I tried that but if u are working with instances of the same app u have to do something similar to alt+tab with the instances of the app, but thanks for the response i will try to use that too :D.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would edit your question to include *all* things you've tried, such that others don't waste time in suggesting something which does not work for you.